# How Enumerate the Prototypes of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

If I create an array like this...

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
```

...the variable "arr" will have various prototypes like "toString" and "forEach".  How could I enumerate the names of all the prototypes of "arr" and get a list like "concat","constructor","entries","every" and so forth?

Comment: Just to clarify: `toString` is *not* a "prototype", it's a property on the object referred to as `Array.prototype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **recursive approach** to print all the properties in the `prototype chain` and not only in the first prototype like in the other answers:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

printAllPrototypeProperties(arr);

function printAllPrototypeProperties(obj) {
  var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);

  if (proto != null) {
    var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto);

    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = (JSON.stringify(properties, undefined, 3));

    return printAllPrototypeProperties(proto);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works in firefox:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf([]));
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype);  //same thing.
/*
result:
length,toSource,toString,toLocaleString,join,reverse,sort,push,pop,shift,unshift,splice,concat,slice,lastIndexOf,indexOf,forEach,map,reduce,reduceRight,filter,some,every,find,findIndex,copyWithin,fill,@@iterator,entries,keys,constructor
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The absolute *best* way to do what you ask is using the following 4 lines of code.

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
forEach.call(Object.getOwnPropertyNames([].__proto__), function(val) {
  console.log(val);
});
```

You may also use forEach directly, but my terminal is only 80 characters long.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) says: "Warning: The `__proto__` property is deprecated and should not be used."  Perhaps you should be using [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

Comment: IMHO if you use a word like "best" you should clarify the fitness criteria you are using to make that subjective judgement.